# What is the difference between Activation layer and activation keyword argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

guys what is the difference between `activation` kwarg and `Activation` layer in tensorflow?

here's an example :

`activation` kwarg :

```
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
```

`Activation` layer :

```
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

PS: im new to tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Dense(64,activation="relu")`, the `relu` activation function becomes a part of `Dense` layer, and will be called automatically whenever this `Dense` layer is called.

In `Activation("relu")`, the `relu` activation function is a layer itself and is decoupled from the `Dense` layer. This is necessary if you want to have a reference to the tensor *after* `Dense` but *before* activation for, says, branching purposes.

```
input_tensor = Input((10,))
intermediate_tensor = Dense(64)(input_tensor)
branch_1_tensor = Activation('relu')(intermediate_tensor)
branch_2_tensor = Dense(64)(intermediate_tensor)
final_tensor = branch_1_tensor + branch_2_tensor

model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=final_tensor)
```

However, your `model` is `Sequential` model so your two samples are effectively equal: the `relu` activation function will be called automatically. To obtain a reference to the tensor before `Activation` in this case, [you can go through `model.layers`](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction) and get the output of the `Dense` layer from within.

Comment: but im getting different results and different accuracy rate

Comment: In your snippets, you use `relu` for the first and `sigmoid` for the second. Also, neural networks training is mostly *stochastic* so you may get different results for different runs even with identical network. However, they should hover around some mean value for the same network and same optimizer.

Comment: are you on discord?

Comment: I am not unfortunately, but feel free to DM me here if my writing is not clear.